# subspace and subspace perp dimensions equal to V

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following statement: if E is a subspace of V, then dim E + dim $E^{\perp}$ = dim V. I know this is true because when these two subspaces are added, they are equal to V, but I'm not sure how to rigorously say this, could I get a little help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First understand the following

$\mathbf{Thereom:}$ Let $\{v_1,…,v_n\}$ be any basis of an inner product space V. Then there exists an orthonormal basis $\{u_1,…,u_n\}$ of V such that the change of basis matrix from $\{v_i\} to \{u_i\}$ is triangular i.e. for $k=1,2.., n$,

$u_k= a_{k1}v_1+a_{k2}v_2+..+a_{kk}v_{k}$

The proof comes from applying the Gram Schmidt algorithm to $\{v_i\}$ to obtain an orthogonal basis and the normalize it to obtain a orthonormal basis of V.

$\mathbf{Theorem:}$ Let W be a subspace of V. Then $V=W \oplus W^{\perp}$

$ \mathbf{Proof:}$ We know that there exists an orthogonal basis $\{u_1,…,u_r\}$ of W and we can extend it to an orthogonal basis , $\{u_1,..,u_n\}$ of V hence we have that $u_{r+1},…,u_n \in W^{\perp}$ , if $v \in V$ then

$v=a_1u_1+…+a_nu_n$, where $a_1u_1+…+a_ru_r \in W$ and $a_{r+1}u_{r+1}+…+a_nu_n \in W^{\perp}$

that is, $V= W+W^{\perp}$

Now suppose that if $w \in W \cap W^{\perp}$ , then $\langle w , w \rangle =0 $ and by properties of inner product this implies $w=0$ hence we have that $W \cap W^{\perp}= \{0\}$ and this completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that $$
V = E + E^\perp
$$ and $$
E \cap E^\perp = \{0\}
$$
then it follows from an elementary theorem.

Comment: How does this relate to dimensions then? I proved the first statement you have

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark Now you can use $dim(E+F)=dim(E)+dim(F)-dim(E\cap F)$.